# Streamlit: Descriptors cannot be created directly

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

[Error Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC5nI.jpg)
Following is the code that I run in the sublime editor:

```
import streamlit as st 
num = st.slider("Choose your number", 1, 100)
st.write('square of ', num, 'is', num ** 2)
```

Can someone please help me find a solution to this?
I was expecting an output.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please follow the advice from @YevhenKuzmovych and also I have run your code on my environment which works fine. So probably check if your streamlit is installed correctly. I would create a new virtual environment, install streamlit, then test it again.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that you need to solve some dependencies issues. Did you try to follow the advice below the error message to downgrade the protobuf package? I am running my streamlit app using

```
protobuf==3.20.1
```

and the code you provided works as expected.